# How to slide-transition two blocks with Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, css-transitions

I'm trying to write a Vue.js transition that slides out an element and at the same time slides in another one. I almost have it working, but the elements bump each other when the animation starts.

[image]

Here is my [CodePen](https://codepen.io/nachocab/pen/MrZwEQ) and the code:

```
// pug/jade
#app
  .elems
    transition-group(name="elem")
      li.elem(v-for="(elem, index) in elems" 
        v-if="index === currentElem" 
        @click="currentElem = currentElem === 0 ? 1 : 0" :key="index") {{ elem 

// stylus
.elems
  display: flex
  align-items: center
  justify-content: center
  height: 100vh
  position:relative

.elem
  display: block
  text-align: center
  font-size: 30px
  padding: 30px
  border-radius: 20px
  border: 2px solid black
  user-select: none
  cursor: pointer

  &-enter-active, &-leave-active
    transition: 1s

   &-enter
     transform: translateX(-100vw)

   &-leave-to
     transform: translateX(100vw)


// js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      elems: ['hello there', 'hello yourself'],
      currentElem: 0
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Try setting the mode on the transition to `out-in`. Setting the display on .elem to `inline-block` will stop the shifting up, also.

Comment: @btl That almost works, but at the end of the animation it snaps back into place. Is there a way to fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need absolute position of the .elem as i understand what you want.
otherwise they cant colide
try this css:

```
.elems
  display: flex
  align-items: center
  justify-content: center
  height: 100vh
  width: 100vw
  position: relative
  overflow: hidden

.elem
  display: block;
  position: absolute
  top: 50%;
  left: 50;
  margin-top: -30px;
  margin-left: -150px
  text-align: center
  width: 300px
  height: 60px
  line-height: 60px
  vertical-align: middle
  font-size: 30px
  border-radius: 20px
  border: 2px solid black
  user-select: none
  cursor: pointer

  &-enter-active, &-leave-active
    transition: 1s

   &-enter
     transform: translateX(-100vw)

   &-leave-to
     transform: translateX(100vw)
```

Comment: Nice, two things: 1) should `left` be `50%`? 2) Is there any way to be more precise defining the top and left margin?

Comment: well if you want to make it centered without knowing the width and height you can

left: 50%;
top: 50%;
transform: translateX (-50%)
transform: translateY (-50%)